# What to do when daycare doesn't allow ill children during winter?

Tags: toddler, daycare, working-parents, sickness

Our 2.5-year-old daughter started her nursery in October. However, the problem with her is that she would have a cold for half of the winter months (so 6+ weeks), and the nursery obviously doesn't allow ill children. We can't take 6 weeks off work just to stay at home with her.

What do people do in these cases?

Comment: Have you checked into why she is getting sick this much?! Maybe an autoimmune disorder or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most nurseries don't kick kids out for a cold or cough as long as the child does not have a fever, however if your nursery is you can take your daughter to the doctor and get a note saying she is okay to go to school.  Most doctors will write a note for a child with a cold, as colds don't go away for a long time.

Comment: +1 This is also the case with our son: a permanently runny nose. But the nursery does not exclude him just because of that.

Comment: I can’t see an answer to the OP’s question.  What does it help that most nurseries don’t act like this? And what if the doctor finds the child has a virus? What if other childs are ill and your child get’s infected? We know that most infections happen in schools, kindergardens and  ... childrenhospitals!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you parents are both working out of house. So if you don’t have grandparents, relateds or friends to take care of a sick child one of you should take free to care for your child.

Comment: From the question: "We can't take 6 weeks off work just to stay at home with her."

Comment: In this case she must have been really seriously infected!